# C pointers do not show to the same address? *pa=a; pa=&a; pa != &pa

Tags: c, pointers

Why isn't it the same memory address? This is in C.

```
  int *pa;    
  int a = 80;
  pa = &a; //save memory address from a to pa
  *pa = 1000; //assign value to that address; *pa and a have now the same value

%p... memory address
%d... decimal

  printf ("a: %d \n", a); //100    
  printf ("*pa: %d \n", *pa); //100
  printf ("pa: %p \n", pa);   //0x7ffcd1370c54
  printf ("&a: %p \n", &a);   //0x7ffcd1370c54
  printf ("&pa: %p \n", &pa); //0x7ffcd1370c60
```

&pa  has always "6" more than pa.

Shouldn't pa, &pa, &a have the same address?

Comment: `pa` stores `&a`. *Where* does it store it?

Comment: yeah, I think that is the problem; I just declared int *pa; *pa was not initialized and therefore no mem was assigned. But even if I init int *pa=79;  the address is off "4"

Comment: `*pa was not initialized and therefore no mem was assigned` - no, `pa` is declared, so memory for it is allocated, but it contains random garbage.

Comment: that is what I thought too, but when you remove the 3rd line ( pa = &a;), suddenly you can not assign to *pa the value 1000.

Comment: "Can not" as in "does not compile" or "does not show 1000 afterwards"?

Comment: I was testing on www.onlinegdb.com and it said "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. Need to test at local machine at home.

Comment: That is because you are writing 1000 to a random address stored in the uninitialized `pa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pa` is the pointer. This pointer holds the reference (address) of `a`

`&pa` is the reference (address) of the pointer `pa` itself and of course it is different than the value which this pointer holds.

You are probably confused by the arrays. The arrays only decal to pointers and they are not pointers itself.

`int arr[5];`

and `arr == &arr` but they hve different types.

Answer (score 2):

`&pa` is actually the address of pa, 
`pa` is the value of pa, thus the address of a

They are different.